# Definition of second cofactor of a matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, terminology, determinant

I am reading a paper and I came across with the term a second cofactor of matrix $M$

Let $C_{ab}$ be the operator cofactor, that is $C_{ab}$(M) is the cofactor o matrix $M$ . Is this the definition second cofactor

$$C_{ab,cd}=C_{ab}\circ C_{cd}$$

?

Here $a$ and $c$ are row of the matrix and $b$ and $d$ columns of the matrix

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the "operator cofactor"? What is "the cofactor o matrix $M$"?

Comment: Perhaps if you told us what paper you are reading, we could make some sense of your question

Comment: I mean cofactor of a determinant.

Comment: I know what the [cofactor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Minor_(linear_algebra)#Definition_and_illustration) of a matrix is if $C_{ab}$ is meant to be a scalar.  I also know what the "cofactor matrix" of a matrix $M$ is. However, I cannot make sense of the sentence "Let $C_{ab}$ be the operator cofactor, that is $C_{ab}$(M) is the cofactor o matrix $M$." For a given $a,b$, is $C_{ab}$ a matrix or a scalar? Also, in your equation, what does the $\circ$ mean?

Comment: $C_{ab}$ is an operator that when it acts on a matrix $M$ produces the scalar $C_{ab}(M)=k_{ab}$ where $k_{ab}$  is the   cofactor of the determinant.

Comment: Here $\circ$ means composition

Comment: Ok, that's clear now, thank you